# Direct sum relations

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A\in \Re$ is a singular matrix, can you give me an example that the direct sum of range of A and null space of A equals to $\Re^n$ does not imply that $R(A)\bot N(A)$

Answer (score 1):

Try $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1 \\ 2&2\end{array}\right).$  Then $$R(A) = \text{span}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 2\end{array}\right)\right\}, \\ N(A) = \text{span}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c} -1\\ 1\end{array}\right)\right\}$$ while $$(1,2)\cdot (-1,1) = 1 \neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Each matrix $A$ with $A^2 =A$ , which does not represent an orthogonal projection will do the job.

For example $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1 \\ 0&0\end{array}\right).$